# Getting rid of taskbar thumbnail previews in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, taskbar, aero

How do I get rid of the window that pops up when I hover a taskbar item?

[image: taskbar preview window]

This is what I have tried with no success, logging out and in after settings have been made:

- Adding a 32-bit DWORD value to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband`
  named `NumThumbnails` with the value `0`.
- Adding a 32-bit DWORD value to the key
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
  named `ExtendedUIHoverTime` with the value `20000`.
- With the group policy editor *gpedit.msc*, navigating to User configuration→ Administrative templates→start menu and tasbar, locating "Turn of taskbar thumbnails" which in swedish seems to be Användarkonfiguration→Administrativa mallar→Start-menyn och Aktivitetsfältet, Inaktivera miniatyrer i Aktivitetsfältet. The setting has been "activated".

Answer (score 1):

I want to remove the preview also then I used [Taskbar Thumbnails Tuner](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.72) to achieved it. Although it said it is working on Windows 7 and 8 only, I have tested it is also working on Windows 10. The step is simple:

1. Click "Disable Thumbnails"
2. Click "Apply"

No need to restart or logout to take effect

Comment: I think I will accept solutions without 3rd party software only. +1